# Suggest me whether to study Razor or basic C# for a developer fluent in HTML and CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm fluent in HTML and CSS and decided to start learning asp.net. I understand the concept of programming and have started to learn to basics of c#; I know that the razor view engine is based on the c# Programming language, but should I start learning razor before fully grasping all concepts of c#?

Comment: Although I know what you mean, "fully grasping all concepts of C#"... Probably just a handful or two on this site that do, and me being a newbie on SO, I can only name two obvious ones. ;-) Much less than "all concepts" will do, but like the answers indicate, you really should be *comfortable* with C# (or VB.NET) before starting on ASP.NET MVC. Razor is easy enough, but that's only a relatively small third of what you'll be doing.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that the razor view engine is based on the c# Programming language

Oh, no. That's wrong. You could perfectly fine use [Razor with VB.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic). The Razor view engine is not tied at all to C#.

> but should I start learning razor before fully grasping all concepts of c#?

Absolutely not. It's the biggest mistake I see so many people doing. You shouldn't even be touching to a web application before learning plain old C#/VB.NET.

Really, not desktop, WPF, web, ... before you learn the .NET base class library and the CLS language syntax of your choice.

And once you start feeling comfortable with the language you could head over to http://asp.net/mvc to get started with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3):

Even though there's alot of synergy going on between C# and Razor, I think I'd recommend you get more comfortable with C# first and then try to get into ASP .NET MVC 3+.  Also, the MVC structure will be new to you and you might find it overwhelming to tackle both at once.

Jon Skeet has [a great introductory series on C# 4.0](http://tekpub.com/productions/csharp4) that you  may enjoy.

If you'd prefer a book over a video (as some do) then I'd [recommend this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471)

Also, for the future, if you like Jon's C# video, Tekpub also has [a good ASP .NET MVC video](http://tekpub.com/productions/mvc3) you could likely step right in to.

Comment: Nice one I appreciate the reply

Comment: Sure thing, I hope it helps.  Good luck.